# Alterative to using arrays in SQLAlchemy

Tags: database-design, sqlalchemy

We have a database created using sqlalchemy with these tables (among others):

```
users                      alarms                       alarm_history
+---------+-----------+    +----------+------------+    +----------+-----------+------------+
| user_id | user_name |    | alarm_id | alarm_name |    | alarm_id | timestamp | alarm_data |
+---------+-----------+    +----------+------------+    +----------+-----------+------------+
```

It might be worth pointing out that these tables have lots of other data in them, this is an abbreviated version, and the alarm_id is related by Foreign Key. There are also many other tables that have relationships.

The Alarms table is like a master list of alarms to be monitored, the History table is just a list of the historic changes to alarm data that is received from an external monitoring service, and the users table is self-explanatory.

What we need to be able to do is have a default list of alarms the user subscribes to (due to the group they belong to), but also be able to choose which alarms to subscribe to or unsubscribe to. This has to be manageable on the fly – they can change this at any time via an API.

How should I store these configurations in the database? The thought would then be to have a 'subscription' column in the user table which points to the configuration it needs to use to determine the set of alarms the user needs to monitor.

- I thought about adding a subscriptions column to the alarms table and it would just be an array/list of IDs that subscribe, but SQL doesn’t store arrays or lists.
- I also thought about having a configurations table detailing the name of each configuration and the alarms it cares about, but you run into the same problem – how do you tell it which alarms it references without an array/list?
- I also thought about generating a new table each time someone creates a new config but reading told me that’s a very bad idea and I don’t even know how to do such a thing.
- I also thought about just parsing a list in the database query using the `IN(<list>)` method, but you get a memory error when the list is longer than ~900 elements so you need to batch the request. Plus it’s not truly relational so it’s slow.

Any pointers on how to get around this issue?

Comment: A suggestion by a colleague was to add an additional table, `current_alarms`,  which is purely the most up to date information for each alarm. As new alarm data is received it appends a new row to the alarm `alarm_history` table, but then overrides any changed data in the `current_alarms` table. This whole table can then be queried and the result can then be quickly processed to remove the unwanted data (either on the server side, or the client side). Then there would be a `configs` table with an ID and a string representation of the alarms which is sent to the user on sign in.

Comment: Another is to simply run a query on the alarm history table sorted by date (descending) and asking for unique alarm IDs only, so it should return one of every alarm, then run an additional filter on the returned result. Neither of these deal well with the possibility of having 100k alarms in total where user A only cares about 20k of them and user B cares about a non intersecting 30k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are rarely used in an RDBMS. The reason is obvious: a relational database system already stores relations in tables, so why add arrays that only represent 1:n relations without the database benefits of foreign key consistency and quick index lookup?

You say a user belongs to a group or even groups (this is not clear). So I'd expect a groups table. If a user belongs to one group, you'll add a `group_id` to the user table. If a user can belong to many groups, you'll add a `user_group` bridge table instead.

A group has default alarms. As one group can have multiple default alarms and one alarm can probably be default for many groups, you'll have an m:n relation, which means a bridge table `group_alarm`.

A user finally decides which alarms to subscribe to. Another m:n relation, another bridge table: `user_alarm`.

So far for the database structure, which is simple enough.

Now to the logic: You want alarms be subscribed to by default. This would mean that you assign the default alarms to the user when you assign a group to the user. This can be done with a trigger that copies the alarms from `group_alarm` to `user_alarm` or by an app. A trigger does this automatically and silently. An app can also do this silently or it can offer a list of checkboxes, so the subscribing/unsubscribing can be done explicitly.

When an alarm is added as a default to a group, I suppose you want nothing to happen. This would only affect new user/group associations, I suppose. Or would you want to add this alarm to the user alarms? If so, again a trigger might be appropriate.

I don't know SQLAlchemy. It is an ORM and ORMs tend to try to convert the net of relations an RDBMS offers into tree structures, which must result in compromises including less convenient and slower access to the data. Suddenly you are forced to deal with a mere programming language to query the data rather than having access to a 4GL query language. So while the above mentioned structure is the appropriate database, I don't know how  working with it may feel in SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Thanks @Thorsten. You're correct, a user belongs to a group and that group has a default set of alarms. I do already have a `user_groups` table (not shown) and users are already related to the group via a `group_id`. I just don't see how the `user_alarm` table stores which alarms a user subscribes to. Unless i misunderstand the term 'bridge table'?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, what appears on the surface to be an unruly duplication of data smooshed into another table (possibly creating a very large table that scales possibly up to `n_alarms x m_alarm_subscription_lists`) is actually the sensible and elegant solution, as well as being quick. This is clearly the solution, even if it does seem ugly, it definitely gets the job done and allows for super quick querying.